# obtain json data from jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Currently, I have a url which renders data in json format.

url:

```
http://10.0.1.11/render?target=threshold(400,test)&from=-1mins&format=json&jsonp=?
```

when run in a browser gives me

```
?([{"target": "test", "datapoints": [[400, 1388755180], [400, 1388755190], [400, 1388755200], [400, 1388755210], [400, 1388755220], [400, 1388755230], [400, 1388755240]]}])
```

I would need the json result in a variable for further processing. I tried the following

```
foo
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON("http://10.0.1.11/render?target=threshold(400,test)&from=-1mins&format=json&jsonp=?", function(result){
   //response data are now in the result variable
   alert(result);
});
</script>
```

I ideally would need:

```
var test = [{"target": "test", "datapoints": [[400, 1388755180], [400, 1388755190], [400, 1388755200], [400, 1388755210], [400, 1388755220], [400, 1388755230], [400, 1388755240]]}];
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with the `result` variable? What processing do you want to do? Do you understand how [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) works and that is has nothing to do with JSON?

Comment: I forgot to add the source,so I was missing the alert. On adding the source, My alert states [object Object]

Comment: You don't say what your problem is. My guess is that you rely in `alert()` to debug, thus get all your data cast to strings. Find your browser's console instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interpret the request as jsonp rather than json. jsonp is like json, but it's json wrapped in a method-call. (see: [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about))

You can use something like:

```
    <script>
    function myCallback(json_data){
        //do something with json_data!

    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.0.1.11/render?target=threshold(400,test)&from=-1mins&format=json&jsonp=myCallback"></script>
```

or

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://10.0.1.11/render?target=threshold(400,test)&from=-1mins&format=json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(json_data){
                        //do something with json_data!
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

(examples adapted from the linked post)

Comment: I'd personally advise against using jQuery yet doing AJAX stuff manually for no apparent reason.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, What do you suggest? I am trying to add tabulation functionality to Giraffe https://github.com/kenhub/giraffe/blob/master/js/giraffe.js. I have the following function http://jsfiddle.net/arg9X/81/